# como utilizar imagem 360°?

Tags: android

Como faço para utilizar uma imagem de 360 ° no android studio?
como se fossem aquelas do facebook que voce vai arrastando a tela com o dedo e vai vendo o restante da imagem , ou entao se o celular tiver giriscopio voce ve o restante da imagem apenas movendo o celular

Comment: Opa, tenta essa solução aqui: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22345293/4532547, tentei achar algo em PT-BR mas nada.. ;x